# What is a good algorithm in C# to find if there exists I,J,K such that 8*I+J*12+K*15=S for some S?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, algorithm, number-theory

I'm building a game in which the player's score goes up by increments of `8`, `12` or `15`. Because it's a JavaScript game that can be (and has been in the past) hacked, I need to do some server-side validation before submitting scores to the database.

For example, a score of `38` makes sense since `30=2*15+1*8`, but a score of `37` doesn't. A score of, say, `912301283` .... well, I'm not sure, because my brain isn't powerful enough to calculate that.

In other words, I'm hoping to figure out a non-brute-force way of filling in

```
private static bool scoreAddsUp ( int score, int [] incs )
{
   // ...
}
```

where `incs = { 8, 12, 15 }` in this case, but of course it would be nice to generalize this procedure in case I change the way the score increments.

**Important questions:**

- Do you have any suggestions for how to write an algorithm from scratch that does this short of using brute force?
- Does the .NET library have any functions that may be useful for this problem?
- Considering that the numbers `8`, `12` and `15` were rather arbitrarily chosen by me, is there a better set of numbers I could use for this procedure? Would using prime numberrs (like `7`, `9`, `13`) allow me to create a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: send `i,j,k` to server and compute a score; `i,j,k` are not unique for a given score: `S = 24`;  when `(i,j,k)=(3,0,0)` or `(i,j,k)=(0,2,0)`

Comment: try bruteforce attack ... `O(n^3)` looks scarry but unless you got really big numbers it should be fine. ... btw @ASh if the score would be in form i,j,k then there is no hack in detection ...  Usually hacks are detected by some kind of CRC ...which this is in a way ...

Comment: After some point all integers can be represented by that algorithm, so it's not very useful for detecting cheats.

Comment: In fact every integer that's 50 or larger is a valid score.

Comment: Hem, a prime number like 9 won't do...

Comment: How this validation will help against hacking in first place? Lowest number is `8`, means it's enough to increment score at most 7 times for passing your check.

Comment: It's javascript, so your scoring algorithm logic is exposed and can be modified so validating the score has no real use versus any decent "hacker". Most likely you would have to send every scoring event to the server and keep track of those and then validate if the submitted score matches the servers score and only accept if it does. But still the "hacker" can just keep spamming the scoring events to the server unless you handle it so that they cannot be spammed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *dynamic programming*:

```
private static Boolean ScoreAddsUp(int score, int[] incs) {
  HashSet<int> completed = new HashSet<int>();

  List<int> frontier = new List<int>() {
    0
  };

  while (frontier.Any(item => item <= score)) {
    for (int i = frontier.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      int front = frontier[i];

      frontier.RemoveAt(i);
      completed.Add(front);

      foreach (int inc in incs) {
        int item = front + inc;

        if (item == score)
          return true;

        if (completed.Contains(item))
          continue;

        frontier.Add(item);
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// Tests
if (!ScoreAddsUp(29, new int[] { 8, 12, 15 }))
  Console.Write("Not Found");

if (ScoreAddsUp(28, new int[] { 8, 12, 15 }))
  Console.Write("Found");
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
if (((score % incs[2]) % incs[1]) % incs[0] == 0)
{
    //remining value is 0, correct score
}
else
{
    //remining value is not 0, incorrect score
}
```

But You should test it to make sure, that there are no false-positive answers

Comment: This would work for `a*i*b*j*c*k` but not for `a*i+b*j+c*k`.